# MongoDB Compass Explain vs Mongoose query

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-compass

I have explained one query on MongoDB Compass and it shows "Actual Query Execution Time (ms): 4"

[image]

However when i run same query on nodejs with mongoose, it takes more than 200 ms.

```
await Model
      .find({
        clientId,
      })
      .lean()
      .select('-_id segment')
      .limit(1200)
      .sort({ createdAt: -1 })
```

Where does the difference come from?
Can someone help?

Comment: That's not the same query - eg different sorts

Comment: Did your test code run the query just once, or multiple times?  The first query run on a mongoose connection will usually have connection and server selection time.

Comment: @Joe I tested multiple times. First query takes like 300ms, everything after the first query takes 200ms.